# How to maintain flow for panels to be loaded?

Tags: javascript, xml, html, web

I need to develop a web page where on click next button new div's get loaded hiding the previous div's.I want externalize this flow.How to maintain a external file or something so the i make changes in that file flow changes accordingly i need every thing to happen in the front end.using JS something need to be done.are there any third party softwares or parser's for this other than XML parser.

Comment: add your code here

Comment: There no code i need a methodology to code it efficiently